# Wrap to span InnerText with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to wrap "Text I want to get" text to  tag and put it back to anchor tag. Is it possible without replacing all inside anchor tag?

Currently I have:

```
<a href="#">
  "Text I want to get"
  <div class="dropdown-icon"><img src="" alt="#">
  </div>
</a>
```

Result I want to achieve:

```
<a href="#">
  <span>Text I want to get</span>
  <div class="dropdown-icon"><img src="" alt="#">
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: I recommend to change the source of the markup.

Answer (score 1):

Pure js solution with `insertBefore` and `appendChild`:

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
links.forEach(link => {
  let wrap = document.createElement("span");
  wrap.className = "colorme";
  link.insertBefore(wrap, link.firstChild);
  wrap.appendChild(link.childNodes[1]);
});
```

```css
.colorme {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  "Text I want to get"
  <div class="dropdown-icon"><img src="" alt="#">
  </div>
</a>
```

You can use Jquery with `contents` and `wrap` like:

```js
$('a').contents().eq(0).wrap('<span class="colorme"/>')
```

```css
.colorme{
  color:red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">
  "Text I want to get"
  <div class="dropdown-icon"><img src="" alt="#">
  </div>
</a>
```

I add `colorme` class just for example.

Comment: This is not a jquery question.

Comment: Jquery == Javascript

Comment: Yes, but Javascript != jquery.

Comment: You wrong symbol !==, because Javascript == Jquery is correct ;)

Comment: No, it does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple piece of code that, in this case, takes the `firstChild` of the hyperlink and uses `replaceChild` to swap the text node for a newly created span element.

```js
let a=document.querySelector('a[href="#"]');
let s=document.createElement('span');
    s.textContent=a.firstChild.textContent;
    a.replaceChild( s, a.firstChild );
```

```css
a span{color:blue}
```

```html
<a href='#'>
  'Text I want to get'
  <div class='dropdown-icon'><img src='' alt='#'>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer!